# WKInterfaceTable not updating after calling removeRowsAtIndexes

Tags: ios8, watchkit, wkinterfacetable

Maybe I'm doing something wrong but if I call `removeRowsAtIndexes:` on a `WKInterfaceTable` instance like so:

```
NSIndexSet *indexes = [[NSIndexSet alloc] initWithIndex:index];
[self.table removeRowsAtIndexes:indexes];
```

Should the table not update? Logging the `numberOfRows` reported by the table shows the number correctly reduced by 1, but on screen nothing changes.

Trying to select a row after this point can actually result in selecting the row below, so clearly the table has recorded the deletion but at least in the simulator it isn't showing.
Has anyone else expereinced this? Is this a bug or do I need to force the table to refresh somehow?

Comment: Running into a similar issue right now, and it has come out of the blue. It was working fine for a while, and now it is just broken. Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class must be fully loaded before you calling removeRows AtIndexes. (when watch interface is visible to user).

```
- (void)willActivate {
    [super willActivate];

    NSIndexSet *indexes = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:index];
    [self.table removeRowsAtIndexes:indexes];
}
```

At what point did you call the method removeRowsAtIndexes in your code ?